# Conversion issues with dates in pandas dataframe and with JSON output

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime, data-conversion

There are two columns in my pandas dataframe that I'm having issues converting to a different date format, both within Python and for when it's returned to the front-end in JSON format. This is what the data looks like from the database:

```
print(df['column1'][0], df['column2'][0])

>> 2019-01-01 00:02:05
>> Name: column1, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>> 01/01/2019 12:02:05 AM
>> Name: column1, dtype: object
```

The first column is in datetime64[ns] (Timestamp?) and the second column is a string object. My goal is to return them to the front-end as the same, in either format.

**Problem 1:** For data under the second column, it returns fine just like that when I return it to the front-end with `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='index', date_format='None'))`, although I am concerned that it isn't changing to another format if I ever do want to change it. It stays like that after I apply `pandas.to_datetime()` or `pandas.Timestamp()` or return as json with `date_format='Epoch'`. Is there a way to convert a string date object like that to, say, ISO datetime object?

**Problem 2:** For the 1st column's data, I want to ideally convert to the string format like for the 2nd column's data (or vice versa) but nothing I've tried worked. In the back-end, it prints that datetime64[ns] format through the attempted conversion with the above functions and others. When I return it to the front-end with `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='index', date_format='None'))`, it defaults to Unix time, e.g. `1546300925000`. It seems like the only options for JSON are either that or ISO format, neither or which I want.

How would I go about converting these formats in the back-end, and returning them in either of the original formats to end front-end?

Comment: did you try to use [to_datetime(..., format=...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) separatelly with every column using different `format=` ?

Comment: I did. `print(df[col1][0], pd.to_datetime(df[col1][0], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))` printed the same unchanged dates and the front-end is still in Unix time.

Comment: After tinkering around with stuff a bit more, I found the to my problem:         `df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))`